# R: Grab only integer from bigz rational number

Tags: r, gmp

Say I have a bigz number

```
library(gmp)
x <- as.bigz(99999)^99
y <- x/66^99
```

Now I want to extract the integer part if this number were written as a mixed number (for example 183 and 15/21). With a smaller number I could `floor(as.numeric(y))` but I will end up loosing precision (with this number in particular R will return `Inf`).

I would like to simply do `floor(y)` but this returns and error unless `y` is a whole number.

We could imagine a simpler case:

```
floor(33/7)
# returns 4
floor(as.bigz(33)/7)
# does not return 4
```

Comment: doesnt applying `as.bigz` extract the integer part .. `x = as.bigz(33)/7; as.bigz(x)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `as.bigz()` to convert the `bigq` (which is what your `y` is) to a big integer:

```
library(gmp)
x <- as.bigz(33)
y <- x/7

as.bigz(y)
# Big Integer ('bigz') :
# [1] 4
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't otherwise need `y` as an intermediate, you could just use the integer division operator, `%/%`, like so:

```
x %/% 7
# Big Integer ('bigz') :
# [1] 4
```